# Google map utility for printed maps?

Tags: maps, google

I'm more of a software guy than a designer, but I've done some design in the past and got talked into doing a print job for a charity.

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a utility to make a printable map from a Google Map? I suspect someone has built an interface somewhere that lets you create a map with markers and icons, and can be easily output to a printable format (PDF or whatever)?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software request rather than a graphic design question. This question may fit better at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Google Maps, but [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) can export to svg, and there are [several utilities](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper) built around it to make the process easier and output to other formats.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) a few times, which allows you to customize and download high resolution (300 or 600dpi) JPG files of an area. Also look at [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78571) question.